# Calling Web Service while showing Splash Screen and setting data fo Initial Screen in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services

I want to load data from Web service while showing the Splash Screen. In the initial Screen I need to display those data. How can I do this ? From where I need to call the webservice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load data from web-service while displaying splash screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722111/how-to-load-data-from-web-service-while-displaying-splash-screen)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must call webservice in your Appdelegate and create globle `NSmutableArray` and use this array in your app
with xml parsiong

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {  

  NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:your url path];

    NSLog(@"path= %@",path);

    [self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];

}
-(void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString*)URL
{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
    RssParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [RssParser setDelegate:self];
    [RssParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
    [RssParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
    [RssParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [RssParser parse];
}

-(void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{   

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{


}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{

}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{

}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError 
{
}

-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{

}
```

Comment: In Appdelegate from which delegate method can I call that webservice?

Comment: befor push a view you can also check that putting NSTimer with 1 second intervel that if Your NSmutable Array count >0 then push a view other wish check again and if your nsmutableArray >0 then stop timer and push a view

Comment: how can I wait for response?

Answer (score 0):

Do this in AppDelegate API

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Make a webservice call in this method. It is the first method that is invoked after main()

Comment: When I am calling webservice from here, before getting data from web ,initial screen is being loaded

Comment: What you can do is simply make you splash screen go to sleep for much longer time. You can sleep the splash screen using this method    sleep(10);

Answer (score 0):

Take one NSTimer at time of launch splash screen.

Put your splash screen in sleep mode.

Store parse data in array.

In the below method of parser

```
-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
if([array count]>0){
//load view whatever you want and display fresh data
}else{
//Alert msg Data not available or display old data if available in database.
}
}
```