# displaying splash screen while downloading images from server in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, splash-screen

in my app i am trying to make a slider using the LWSlideShow [LWSlideShow](https://github.com/imhui/LWSlideShow)
the source of images are fetched from my server after trying the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722111/how-to-load-data-from-web-service-while-displaying-splash-screen) i stuck with error that said unbalanced call and it means that i am presenting a modal view on a view that did not completed his animation after solving this problem by putting animation to no the splashView that i present will be dismissed before the images are downloaded here is my code for further explanation:

```
 - (IBAction)goDownload {

    UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Splash"];
        [self.navigationController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSMutableArray *array = [@[] mutableCopy];
        LWSlideItem *item = [LWSlideItem itemWithCaption:@""
                                                imageUrl:@"http://code-bee.net/geeks/images/cover-1.jpg"];
        [array addObject:item];
        item = [LWSlideItem itemWithCaption:@""
                                   imageUrl:@"http://code-bee.net/geeks/images/cover-2.jpg"];
        [array addObject:item];
        item = [LWSlideItem itemWithCaption:@""
                                   imageUrl:@"http://code-bee.net/geeks/images/cover-3.jpg"];
        [array addObject:item];





        LWSlideShow *slideShow = [[LWSlideShow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), 120)];

        slideShow.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

        //slideShow.delegate = self;
        [self.view addSubview:slideShow];
        slideShow.slideItems = array;



        if ([slideShow.slideItems count] == [array count]) {
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }



    });









}





//
//-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
//{
//
//    UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Splash"];
//    [self.navigationController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
//}




- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];




    [self goDownload];
    }
```

also you can see from the code that also i try to use viewWillAppear same thing happened what i want is when the images are downloaded the splashView need to be dismissed i dont know what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running that code from a VC anytime before viewDidAppear (like viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear) will cause the problem you describe. But you probably don't want the slide show view to appear - even for an instant - until you're done fetching the assets.  This is a common problem.

The solution is to realize that the "splash screen" and the network tasks aren't just preamble, they are as much a part of your application as the slide show.

**EDIT**
Make that Splash vc the app's initial view controller in storyboard.  Right now, the slide show vc probably looks like this:

[image]

Uncheck the "Is Initial View Controller" checkbox, find your splash view controller (in the same storyboard, I hope) and check it's box to be the initial view controller.  Now your app will start up on the splash vc, like you want it.

When the splash vc done, it can present the slide show vc, or it can even replace itself (with the slide show ) as the app window's root.

To replace the UI, I use variations of this snippet...

```
// in the splash vc, after all of the asset loading is complete

// give what used to be your initial view controller a storyboard id
// like @"MySlideShowUI"

UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MySlideShowUI"];

UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window;
window.rootViewController = vc;

[UIView transitionWithView:window
                  duration:0.3
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:nil
                completion:nil];
```

Comment: can you provide more details about how to solve my problem

Comment: Which part did I not explain enough?

Comment: Make that Splash vc the app's initial view controller in storyboard. When it's done, it can present the slide show vc, or it can even replace itself (with the slide show ) as the app window's root.

Comment: if you know uber app when u launched the app there is a splash screen will go untill the data had been loaded

Comment: and then how to get back to tabbarcontroller

Comment: I didn't realize your slide show vc was in a tab bar controller.  That's okay, give that tab bar controller a storyboard id.  (you know how to do that.... the same way you gave the id "Splash" to the splash vc).  Call it "MySlideShowUI" to match the code I suggested.  Then, the code I suggested creates that tab bar controller and makes it a child of the app window.  You're off and running, like Uber.  See the comment in the code I suggested?  Run it *after* any downloading is done

Comment: The slide show is not a viewController its a view inside the viewController

Comment: Whatever view controller it appears in, thats the one whose id should be "MySlideShowUI".  If that's a vc inside a tab bar controller, put that id on the tab bar controller.

Comment: Let me give you a full description about the UIStoryboard there is a splash screen that will run until the images are downloaded there is tab bar controller contain the mSinviewcontroller which have the LWslideshow embedded inside it after all slide show items had been added to the slide show the splash screen should be dismissed modally and then open the tab bar controller

Comment: Yes.  Give that tab bar controller an identifier as I suggest.  Put the code I suggest into the splash vc after its done downloading images.

Comment: I will try your solution on the evening now i am at work but let me ask question after downloading images in the splash vc can i save them to nsuserdeffsult as key and value ??

Comment: No, not images.  Those must be saved as files in the app's NSDocumentsDirectory or NSCachesDirectory

Comment: That mean i need to download the imsges in splashviewcontroller.m and cache them then acces them from maincontroller.m

Comment: Forget to tell you that the LWSlideShow use AFNetworking library to download images from the server

Comment: Where to put the images so they can be downloaded by the splash and used by the other is a big topic.  Google for singletons in objective c.  Regarding your other comment, the AFNetworking calls need to go in the splash vc.  The whole point of this is to do that downloading there.  The slideshow thing needs to assume the images are available.

Comment: startup sequence is that app starts on splash vc, it calls AFNetworking to get images.  When they are downloaded it saves them in a singleton.  Then it replaces the app window root view controller with whatever contains the slideshow, the slideshow knows to go look in the singleton for the images that were just downloaded